# Javascript function returns undefined when the value is clearly set

Tags: javascript, html, function, return

Very simple but... Weird
The value of b is clearly settled as you can see on the console but it returns undefined.

```
function loopMe(n,b){
  b++;
  console.log(n+' '+b);
  if(n===0){
    return b
  }
  loopMe(--n,b);
}

console.log(loopMe(5,3));
```

You can clearly see the value of b within the function so why it's not returning it?

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply forgetting to `return` your recursive call to `loopMe`.

```js
function loopMe(n,b){
  b++;
  console.log(n+' '+b);
  if(n===0){
    return b
  }
  return loopMe(--n,b);
}

console.log(loopMe(5,3));
```